# List item click triggering child view's selector

Tags: android, listview

I have an ImageView in my layout for the individual items of a list.

The ImageView's src is an XML file in the drawable folder that defines which images to use during the various states of pressing an item.

However, I've noticed when you click the list row (and not the ImageView itself) the selector assigned to the ImageView is activated.  It doesn't actually hit the ImageView's onClick code, but the image toggles as if it has been clicked.

This is actually a desirable effect in some cases, but in this specific case it is not.  Is there a way I can stop this from happening?

Comment: Can you post your code for us please?

Comment: Totally depends upon how u have implemented it. Maybe some code would help us figure it out.

Comment: There's nothing to really show you other than XML...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should read Cyril Mottier's blog. He has a post about this [here](http://android.cyrilmottier.com/?p=525).

In a word, you have to extends your Child views to Override the method `setPressed(boolean)` like this:

```
    @Override
    public void setPressed(boolean pressed) {
        if (pressed && getParent() instanceof View && ((View) getParent()).isPressed()) {
            return;
        }
        super.setPressed(pressed);
    }
```

Answer (score 11):

set `android:duplicateParentState` in child to `true`